# Casting generic typed object to subtype

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following scenario in my code:

```
class Document
{}

class Track : Document
{}

class ViewListClickHandler
{
    // I can't change that signature, it's provided by a library I use.
    protected override void click(object theList, int index)
    {
        // I here need to cast "theList" to IList<T> where T : Document
    }
}
```

My question now is (as written at the comment):

How can I cast that `theList` to a type like `IList<T> where T : Document`?

The difficulty in this case is, that I can get any class, extending `Document` in that list. And it's the same for me what I get. I just want to cast it to a list containing some documents.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, forgot to mention that. `theList` sometimes is an object, compatible to `IList<Document>`, sometimes `IList<Track>` or generically typed to some other subtype of `Document`.

I need to do that in a one-liner. I have another example, where it isn't an IList, but another generically typed class, where I can't loop.

Comment: @defaultlocale: Sorry ... forgot to rename some variables in the comments and the text below.

Comment: @defaultlocale `an individual article or unit, especially one that is part of a list, collection, or set.` :)

Comment: @defaultlocale Feels like recursion. Maybe I'll write a method for you. I'm only good for 1 word a day. I read 9 questions without knowing the answer, then I saw yours and thought hey, I can google that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var documents = theList.OfType<Document>();
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution for this case. Will accept it here. I guess, I have to post another question for the same case for classes, where I can't use LinQ ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here are covariance and contravariance. For subtypes casting you need to have a generic covariant interface.
IEnumerable and IQueryable are a good examples of that. The only thing that you need is that every method of this interface only return objects of type T (covariance) or if the interface methods only receive object of type T (contravariance) and you interface definition need the in/out word.
EX:

```
// covariance
public interface ICovarianct<out T>{
    IEnumerable<T> Get();
}

// contravariance
public interface Contravariant<in T>{
    void Method(T arg)
}
```

Then in your specific sample you can not use casting because IList isn't covariant. You can use LINQ extensions like:

```
OfType<T>() //to enumerate only the items of certain types.

all.OfType<Document>()
```

will returns all the Documents in the collection

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Just call `(IList<Document>) theList` or if elements are not `Documents` do 2-step way: First cast `object theList` to `IList<object>`. Then iterate every element and check if it is a `Document`.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it in a one-liner?

Comment: Something like this `((IList)theList).Where(x is Document).Select(x => (Document)x).ToList();`

Comment: By the way: one-liner is not always the best choose

Comment: Yea, and in this case I confirm, that it works using LinQ, because it's a list ... I just thought I'd get also another use-case in here, where I don't have a list, but need the same kind of type-casting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast to an open generic type - why not just cast to `IList<Document>`? It's not entirely clear, but it seems you are saying you will only call the method with a list of documents?

Answer (score -1):

```
//Provided that theList was either List<Track> or List<Document> or any class derived from Document. You can just cast using this statement

List<Document> documents = theList as List<Document>;
```

Comment: Sure? I get a NullPointerException when `theList` is an instance of `List<Track>` in the next line, I try to call a method or access a property of `theList`.

Comment: Can you verify that theList is actually List<Track> by using Console.WriteLine(theList.GetType().ToString()); I had a feeling that the library you use has encapsulate the object

Comment: No it doesn't. You can't cast `List<T>` to `List<Base>`.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry i was relying on my memory. Didn't have the compiler in front of me atm so can't test