# C# - How to cast an object to a generic type for a subclass?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following code at hand:

```
class Document {}
class Track : Document {}
class Album : Document {}

class CellWrapper<T> {}

class TableViewSource {

    protected void CreateCellForItem(object item) {
        // item is an instance of CellWrapper<T> where T is a document extending Document
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to cast `item` to `CellWrapper<Document>`?

I know, that you can define something for a method where I need something like that, but I wasn't able to find something working for this case. I am only able to confirm (not cast) that it's an instance of CellWrapper ...

Something like this does not compile:

```
CellWrapper<Document> wrapper = item as CellWrapper<T> where T : Document;
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify that: This question is different from [Casting generic typed object to subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604057/casting-generic-typed-object-to-subtype) as the named one only has a solution if `item` is an object, that is enumerable, like `IList`. In my example, it's a custom class. The solutions provided there are not applicable to my issue here.

Comment: Why are you accepting an `object` type to begin with?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, That is part of an interface ... I can't change it.

Comment: This here might help if you have a chance of solving it without reflections: http://igoro.com/archive/fun-with-c-generics-down-casting-to-a-generic-type/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access a property of the type T, you can access the property by using reflection. However, this does not cast the value to `CellWrapper<Document>`:

```
class Document {
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
class Track : Document {}
class Album : Document { }

class CellWrapper<T> where T : Document {
    public T Document { get; set; }
}

class TableViewSource
{

    public void CreateCellForItem(object item)
    {
        var documentProperty = item.GetType().GetProperty("Document");
        var document = (Document)documentProperty.GetValue(item);
        Console.WriteLine(document.Key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just this:

```
 CellWrapper<Document> wrapper = item as CellWrapper<Document>;
```

Comment: That fails if you have an instance of `CellWrapper<Track>` or `CellWrapper<Album>` ...